# Creating custom models for skulls/heads, fences and banners

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm working on a project with a specific resource pack (1.19.2). For my project, I need a custom model that's able to face multiple directions (not just north/east/south/west/up/down). There are only three blocks in the game that support that: signs, banners and skulls/heads.

I already have the model ready and I have yet tested it on the fence model. So, I tried applying it to skull models. However, no matter what I try, no matter what .json I replace in the resource pack folder, the default model is still being used. I've replaced the item/skull model, item/template_skull model, , block/skull model and the skeleton_skull blockstate file. However, just nothing works. Same applies for sign- and banner models.

It's really important that the blocks can face more directions, so using another block is not a solution.